# Git - How to remove remote by URL

Tags: git, git-remote

I've tried searching for how to remove remote by URL but all suggestions is to remove entire remote and re-add required URLs.

Initially, I've added the url using command,

```
git remote set-url --add --push all C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\TestPath
```

Then, amongst all the available urls in the config file, how do I remove just this particular URL line? (highlighted yellow)
[image: config file]

I did try the following command `git remote set-url --delete all C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\TestPath`
But I received this error -> `could not unset 'remote.all.url'`

I've also checked for available paths using `git config --list --show-origin` just to reconfirm the value is only coming from this one specific file.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `--push` parameter, and also use two slashes in the url path (so it will be written in the same way as in configuration file).

```
git remote set-url --delete --push all C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\TestPath
```

`--push` parameter will indicate that push URLs are manipulated instead of fetch URLs ([git remote documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))

Comment: Life saviour! Thanks, now I also know what is --push parameter for.